# How do I keep track of users info without having them log in (Using asp.net mvc4 with Visual Studio)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, web

New developer here.  I'm building a website that has users play a series of games and tracks their decision making.  I haven't found a good way to keep track of these users as they move through the series of games.  Do you have any suggestions for the best way to do this without forcing each to make a profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be done using [HTTP Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

[Here's a tutorial on how to use them in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies)